# How to keep zsh histories separate by application?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using zsh for system administration and development. The development part happens mostly in VS Code where I use git commands and stuff like that. Is it possible to open a zsh instance specifically for development such that I don't have git stuff in the history of my system terminal and vice versa? Something like a dedicated profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible, first of all make a new zsh configuration file for development(for example `.zshrc_dev`) and then add any customizations or configurations specific to your development environment, now in your main zsh configuration file, usually located at `~/.zshrc`, add this lines at the end of file :

```
if [ -f ~/.zshrc_dev ]; then
    source ~/.zshrc_dev
fi
```

now, whenever you want to open a zsh instance specifically for development, you can do so by running the following command in your terminal:

```
zsh --rcfile ~/.zshrc_dev
```